# Get Details of Guest Quote in OPC

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, guest-checkout

I am using magento 1.9.

I want to get the quote details of guest in the shipping method step. I tried using this code

> Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getData();

But, It returns null on the first time of checkout. But returns data after refresh the page.

Comment: try ` Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();`

Comment: I need shipping method, shipping cost, billing address , shipping address and grand total values. but it gives only grand total. :(

Comment: where exactly you are calling `Mage::getModel('checkout/session')` ?

Comment: I have added a opc step using http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/10/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step. I am calling from that file